# SQL Server: Need to select an employee with minimum idle time in a query with min function

Tags: sql-server, query-performance

I want to select `employeeID` of the `employee` with minimum idle time in the table. It is a simple query but I am confused with it. I tried a query like this:

```
SELECT    dbo.tbSystemUser.EmployeeID,tbEmployee.Name
FROM      dbo.tbSystemUser INNER JOIN
          dbo.tbEmployee ON dbo.tbSystemUser.EmployeeID = dbo.tbEmployee.EmployeeID
WHERE     (dbo.tbSystemUser.Time = MIN(dbo.tbSystemUser.Time))
```

But it is not working. Time is the field which stores time and is of datatype time.

Comment: Something like Select top 1 employeeID order by minimumTime ? Do you need WITH TIES when more than 1 employee has the same minimum time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
SELECT tbl.*, tbEmployee.name 
FROM (
    SELECT tbSystemUser.employeeid, min(t) AS t
    FROM tbSystemUser JOIN tbEmployee
      ON tbSystemUser.employeeid = tbEmployee.employeeid
    GROUP BY tbSystemUser.employeeid
) tbl, tbEmployee 
WHERE tbl.employeeid = tbEmployee.employeeid 
  AND tbl.t = tbEmployee.t
```

Here is sample data:

```
create table tbSystemUser (
employeeid varchar(10))

create table tbEmployee (
employeeid varchar(10),
name varchar(10),
t integer
)

insert into tbSystemUser values('a')
insert into tbSystemUser values('b')

insert into tbEmployee values('a', 'q', 1)
insert into tbEmployee values('a', 'w', 2)
insert into tbEmployee values('a', 'e', 3)

insert into tbEmployee values('b', 'z', 1)
insert into tbEmployee values('b', 'x', 2)
insert into tbEmployee values('b', 'c', 3)
```

Or even simpler:

```
SELECT tbl.*, tbEmployee.name 
FROM (
    SELECT employeeid, min(t) as t 
    FROM tbEmployee
    GROUP BY employeeid) tbl, tbEmployee
WHERE tbl.employeeid = tbEmployee.employeeid
  AND tbl.t = tbEmployee.t
```